# How to apply patch on mapserver?

Tags: php

Actually I have a problem for installing php mapscript on php5.6 and I asked it on the oerdnj github (https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/461). He gave me the answers to compile the mapserver source but because he is really busy, I stuck on a step to apply the patch on mapserver. I tried to copy the patch and store it in a file 'oerdnj.patch' in mapserver-6.4.1 directory. Here is the file content

```
--- debian/rules~   2014-02-28 15:54:20.000000000 +0000
+++ debian/rules    2016-09-26 14:19:52.177217057 +0000
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ CFLAGS+=$(CPPFLAGS)
 CFLAGS+=$(LDFLAGS)

 RUBYVERSIONS=$(shell dh_ruby --print-supported)
-PHP5API=$(shell php-config5 --phpapi)
+PHP5API=$(shell php-config5.6 --phpapi)
 MANPAGES:=$(wildcard debian/man/*.*.xml)

 MS_VERSION=$(shell dpkg-parsechangelog | sed -ne 's/^Version: \(.*\)-.*/\1/p')
--- debian/control~ 2014-02-28 15:54:20.000000000 +0000
+++ debian/control  2016-09-26 14:20:28.385182799 +0000
@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@ Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9),
                libgif-dev,
                librsvg2-dev,
                libpq-dev,
-               php5-dev,
+               php5.6-dev,
                swig,
                libperl-dev,
                python-all (>= 2.6.6-3~),
```

I tried to apply the patch like this:

```
teddy@teddy-K43SJ:~/mapserver-6.4.1$ patch -p1 < oerdnj.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- debian/rules~   2014-02-28 15:54:20.000000000 +0000
|+++ debian/rules    2016-09-26 14:19:52.177217057 +0000
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

I got the above error and I also have no idea about file to patch. So how to make the patch work? I never done this before

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can patch it with paramater -p0 instead of -p1 as suggested [here](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/461)

```
teddy@teddy-K43SJ:~/mapserver-6.4.1$ patch -p0 < oerdnj.patch
patching file debian/rules
patching file debian/control
```

I'm not sure but I dont get any error anyway